# RxJs MergeMap returning null?

Tags: angular, rxjs

I have a simple service:

```
addBatchTags(tagList: string[], questionId: number) {
      return this.http.post(
          this.baseUri + "AddBatchTagsToQuestion/?tags=" + tagList + "&questionId=" + questionId, {observe: 'response'}
        ).pipe(
        catchError(err => of(err))
      );
    }
```

My component is this:

```
 submitQuestion(form: NgForm) {
    if (form.valid) {
      if (this.questionModel.content != '' && this.questionModel.content != '') {
        this.spinner.show();

        this.questionService.createQuestion(this.questionModel)
        .pipe(
          mergeMap(
            (resp) => {
              return this.tagQuestionService.addBatchTags(this.tags, resp.body.id)
            }
          )
        ).subscribe(
          (data: any) => {
            console.log(data)     
            this.spinner.hide();
          }
        )
      }
    }
  }
```

However, my console log in the component subscription is returning null instead of the full response of the API call inside the merge map. Checking the network tab and database, everything is actually working.

Comment: Hmmm...I have no idea but maybe I can help anyway but suggesting ways to figure out what's going on? Put `tap(x => console.debug(x, 'before mergeMap'),` immediately before mergeMap, and also log errors and completion in your subscribe call? Also, not knowing the rest of your code, question `this`; make sure addBatchTags is getting the right values.